# Using Frames in IE10 causes SCRIPT5002: Function expected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I've been doing quite a bit of scouring of the internet and haven't yet been able to find a solution to this issue.  What is happening is that I have a page that renders in a frame depending on the navigation click.  This functionality works and has worked for years in all other browser versions prior to IE10, and continues to work flawlessly in Compatibility Mode, but I don't want compatibility mode.  Basically when my functions reaches this line of code;

```
window.parent.frames(1).location='../frmsetPage.aspx?
sFrameScrolling=yes&pageurl=secCreating_Editing/secContent/wfContent.aspx?iPageID=' + 
p_iSitePageID + '&helpurl=secHelp/wfHelp.aspx?iBuilderPageID=29'
```

i get the error of;

SCRIPT5002: Function expected

Of all the research I have been doing the only thing that made any sense is talking about depriciation of the window.parents.frames(1) object, but I can't seem to validate that through anything from Microsoft so I really have no idea.

any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much,
NickG

Comment: You are not calling a frames method! It should be square brackets.

Comment: `.frames(1).` should be `.frames[1].` frames is an array of all frames, not a function.

Comment: why would this work in compatibility mode and on all other browsers for the past couple years if had to do with the frames array reference not being correct syntax?  Is it just that IE10 has created more strict standards when referencing this stuff?

Comment: Because the web is essentially (scarcely documented) tag-soup and historically a part of the browser-war was to try and make sense of 'crappy/illegal/idiotic' code. Specifying compatibility-mode will re-enable the unpredictable 'I can guess better then browserX' code inside IE. Crockford is right, the best solution is to start over. Meanwhile, simply learn [Polyglot markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot/) just like the rest of the web-devs who distilled the standards down to something reliable over the last 15 years. With all respect, it makes more sense then unstandardised html5 ideas.

Comment: PS, out of (historic) interest (and possibly for laughs at the expense of M$), could you share a official M$ doc that uses `frames(#)` instead of `frames[#]` ? (Since you've just freshly scoured the internet, researching your frame-problem.)

Comment: @GitaarLAB I just have met a similar problem and found this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which produces 'function expeced'

Comment: @ChrisLo: cool, thanks for that link, you know what they say: a laugh a day keeps the doctor away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
window.parent.frames[1].location='../frmsetPage.aspx?
sFrameScrolling=yes&pageurl=secCreating_Editing/secContent/wfContent.aspx?iPageID=' + 
p_iSitePageID + '&helpurl=secHelp/wfHelp.aspx?iBuilderPageID=29'
```

instead of:

```
window.parent.frames(1).location='../frmsetPage.aspx?
sFrameScrolling=yes&pageurl=secCreating_Editing/secContent/wfContent.aspx?iPageID=' + 
p_iSitePageID + '&helpurl=secHelp/wfHelp.aspx?iBuilderPageID=29'
```

Reason: the `frames` collection is accessed like an array using `[]` instead of `()`.

Good luck!